# Knife search environments and roles with a field using a wildcard

Tags: solr, chef-infra, knife

I'm changing an attribute from:

```
default['splunk']['auth'] = "admin:changeme"
```

to:

```
default['splunk']['auth']['username'] = "admin"
default['splunk']['auth']['password'] = "changeme"
```

and I want to be sure that I don't miss / forget something...

It's easy enough to be sure I didn't miss anything in cookbooks:

```
nickh@BONHENRY:~/Repositories/chef$ ack-grep "\[.splunk.?\]\[.auth.?\]"
cookbooks/splunk_cookbook/attributes/default.rb
36:default['splunk']['auth']['username']          = "admin"
37:default['splunk']['auth']['password']          = "changeme"

cookbooks/splunk_cookbook/attributes/README.md
72:* `node['splunk']['auth']['username']` - The default admin username to use instead of splunks "admin"
73:* `node['splunk']['auth']['password']` - The default admin password to use instead of splunks "changeme"

cookbooks/splunk_cookbook/recipes/server.rb
219:  command "#{splunk_cmd} edit user admin -password #{node['splunk']['auth']['password']} -roles admin -auth admin:changeme && echo true > /opt/splunk_setup_passwd"
228:    command "#{splunk_cmd} enable listen #{node['splunk']['receiver_port']} -auth #{node['splunk']['auth']['username']}:#{node['splunk']['auth']['password']}"
326:      command "#{splunk_cmd} edit licenser-localslave -master_uri 'https://#{node['splunk']['dedicated_search_master']}:8089' -auth #{node['splunk']['auth']['username']}:#{node['splunk']['auth']['passwor
391:    command "/opt/splunk/bin/splunk login -auth #{node['splunk']['auth']['username']}:#{node['splunk']['auth']['password']}"

cookbooks/splunk_cookbook/recipes/forwarder.rb
78:execute "#{splunk_cmd} edit user admin -password #{node['splunk']['auth']['password']} -roles admin -auth admin:changeme && echo true > /opt/splunk_setup_passwd" do
```

However, I'm not sure of a good way to grep/search JSON roles/environments for the same...

This works:

```
 nickh@BONHENRY:~/Repositories/chef$ knife search environment "override_attributes_splunk_auth:*" -i
 1 items found

 prod-acme
```

However, do you have any idea why this works:

```
 nickh@BONHENRY:~/Repositories/chef$ knife search environment "*:*" -i
 108 items found
```

but this doesn't? :

```
 nickh@BONHENRY:~/Repositories/chef$ knife search environment "*splunk_auth:*" -i
 ERROR: knife search failed: invalid index name or query
```

Is there an easy / better way to do it that I'm not thinking of / unaware of? Can I change something w/ my Solr query that would make it work?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `*:*` is a special case in the search system that bypasses Solr entirely. Chef's search index uses a transformed version of the query such that I don't think it would be safe to use a glob in the facet name like that. I would recommend running `knife download environments/` (and similar for roles) and then doing your grep on the local JSON files.